# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme but I am using it?

Tags: java, android

You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme problem, but i'm currently using it.
But I have AppCompat so I don't know what's the problem is it:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerItems.with(this)
            .add(R.string.tab1, Rate.class)
            .add(R.string.tab2, Genres.class)
            .add(R.string.tab3, Rate.class)
            .add(R.string.tab4, Genres.class)
            .add(R.string.tab5, Genres.class)
            .create());
```

Manifest:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"

        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

styles.xml

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

gradle

```
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v13:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Logcat:

```
Process: xxx, PID: 826
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx/xxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
                                                                   at .MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
```

Comment: Try to rebuild your project

Comment: seems it helped but ... third rebuild, android studio have some problems :) thx for solution

Comment: What's your minsdk ?

Comment: Try removing the action bar and setting it to `Theme.AppCompat.Light` Instead of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Hope it helps

Comment: This is really odd. I am shooting in the dark with this, but by any chance are you redefining `Theme.AppCompat` in your styles.xml? Does the app work if you remove `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` from your activity tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I wonder if you read people that first solution worked